# Xamarin.Forms - ListView isn't being updated in the OnAppearing method

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm developing an app with Xamarin.Forms, I've a screen where the user can publish a feed update, this feed update contains text and some attached files. My xaml view is basically, a `StackLayout` that contains a `ListView`, and `Editor` and a couple of `Buttons`. The problem is that I'm trying to set the `ItemSource` of my `ListView` in the `onAppearing` method. The method is being called just fine. The collection that I'm setting changes as is expected. But for some reason the `ListView` isn't being updated. A workaround that made the `ListView` work was right after setting the `Source` call the `Editor` focus method. I did because I figured out that when I clicked in the editor after the collection was suppously set, the `ListView` rendered properly. But well is a very nasty workaround.

Here's my xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="HalliganTL.View.UpdateFeedPage">
  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
    <ListView x:Name="AttachedFilesListView" MinimumHeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Button Text="[X]" />
              <StackLayout Padding="5,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Medium" />
              </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Editor x:Name="UpdateFeedEditor" FontSize="15" Text="{Binding PostText}"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    <Button Text="Attach file" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#77D065" Clicked="onAttachFileClicked"/>
    <Button Text="Post" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#77D065" Clicked="onPostClicked"/>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Here's my page code:

```
public partial class UpdateFeedPage : ContentPage
    {
        public static List<FileObject> CurrentSelectedFile = new List<FileObject>();
        public static string PostText = "";

        public UpdateFeedPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Title = "New Update";
            UpdateFeedEditor.Text = PostText;
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            AttachedFilesListView.ItemsSource = CurrentSelectedFile;
            UpdateFeedEditor.Focus();
            base.OnAppearing();
        }

        async void onPostClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
        }

        async void onAttachFileClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new FilePickerPage());
        }
    }
```

I played with a lot of things like:

- Changing the HorizontalOptions and the VerticalOptions from the ListView and the StackLayout that contains the ListView.
- Removed all other controls except the StackLayout and the child ListView.

But nothing worked so far, except calling the Editor, Focus method programatically

**NOTE:**

As you can see the ListView collection that I'm setting is static, I modify that collection directly from another page, but I think that is OK, because when I set a breakpoint in the OnAppearing the collection was being modify properly.

Comment: When you say `"ListView isn't being updated"` does that mean that you already viewed the `UpdateFeedPage`,  gone to a different page and are returning? Or is it the `first time` that you are viewing the `UpdateFeedPage`

Comment: Means that I already viewed the UpdateFeedPage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two ways to fix that refresh issue.

**1st way)**

Force the ListView to refresh from your `List<FileObject>` collection by resetting the `ItemsSource`:

**Current:**

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    AttachedFilesListView.ItemsSource = CurrentSelectedFile;
    UpdateFeedEditor.Focus();
    base.OnAppearing();
}
```

**Change to:**

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    AttachedFilesListView.ItemsSource = null;
    AttachedFilesListView.ItemsSource = CurrentSelectedFile;
}
```

**2nd way)**

Replace your `List<FileObject>` collection with an `ObservableCollection<FileObject>` so changes are published via `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add|Remove|...` based events that the `ListView` will be listening to.

**Current:**

```
public static List<FileObject> CurrentSelectedFile = new List<FileObject>();
```

**Change to:**

```
public static readonly ObservableCollection<FileObject> CurrentSelectedFile = new ObservableCollection<FileObject>();
```

*Note: Also add a `using System.Collections.ObjectModel;`*

Your `OnAppearing` becomes:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    AttachedFilesListView.ItemsSource = CurrentSelectedFile;
}
```

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged, the gift that keeps on giving.

Comment: Amazing! both solutions worked perfectly, I obviously choosed the second one.