# Refreshing selected item ListView Xamarin Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im trying to refresh a selectedItem in the list view. I click an item in the list which navigates to another page including the items that are in the selected item. Then i update the details and click the save button. Then im navigated back to the listview page.

The data is changed in the database but the selected item in the list view still shows the old value.

How can I refresh the item that i changed?

It shows the new value when i pull to refresh, but i need it to refresh when i click the save button which is in another content page. Please help me.

```
GuestInfo gi = new GuestInfo ();
MessagingCenter.Send (this, "hi", "1");
gi.guestDetailsUpdated ();
```

In the above section im adding the sending the information using message center, Which is in once content page.

```
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe(this, "hi", sender => {
            RetrieveReservationList();
        });
```

Above code is in another content page which should triger the mesage that was sent to identify the button click given from the other page to for this page to refresh.

guestInfo is a content page.
RetriveReservtionList is the method to get data.
guestDetailsUpload is the method in the other content page which is triggered from the button clicked page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin.Forms - ListView isn't being updated in the OnAppearing method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400239/xamarin-forms-listview-isnt-being-updated-in-the-onappearing-method)

Comment: Hi, Will u be able to do a sample for me? its difficult to understand since the save button is in another content page

Comment: Whatever method you are calling for the PullToRefresh could be called on the `OnAppearing` method of the `Page` that is not refreshing. Without posting any code that you are having an issue with it is tough to provide a solution to your problem ;-)

Comment: Hi, How can i call the pull to refresh method in on appearing? It has two parameters that i need to pass. What should I Pass in there?

Comment: Also note that the page that has the list view is a tab in a content page. When I click an item I use the "await Navigation.PushAsync" method to go to the page that i edit the selected list view item. Once I save, I need to return back to the Tab page with a Refreshed List view. Am I doing it right? Im using the "this.Navigation.RemovePage (this);" to remove the navigated page to go back to the Tab page.

Comment: What is your data source? A `list<xxx>` ?

Comment: Yes, A observable collection added to a list..... "items = new ItemList (guestdetails);
   GuestListView.ItemsSource = items.Items;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of doing that.

First of all you can refresh your list data every time page appears on screen, that is `OnAppearing` method is called. Let's assume you have a `MyViewModel` with a property `MyItems` to which you bind your ListView's ItemSource. Also you should have a method `LoadMyItems` which will fetch the items from database or perhaps web service and assign the value to `MyItems`. In your page class you'll do something like this

```
public class MyPage : ContentPage
        {
            private MyViewModel _viewModel;
            public MyPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                _viewModel = new MyViewModel();
                BindingContext = _viewModel;
            }

            protected override void OnAppearing()
            {
                base.OnAppearing();
                _viewModel.LoadMyItems();
            }
        }
```

So, every time your screen is shown the data will be updated. This approach will always cause your list view to refresh, wether the data was changed or no. There is better more efficient way of doing this.

You can use broadcast messages, in Xamarin.Forms it's `MessagingCenter`. You can find a good article [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-xamarinforms-and-messaging--cms-22526). Basically what you need to do is send a message when you save an item and catch that message in your `ViewModel` and update `MyItems`.

Send a message when you save a item into your database

```
MessagingCenter.Send(this, "MyItemsChanged");
```

In your view model, subscribe to that message and update reload your items.

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe(this, "MyItemsChanged", sender => {
                LoadMyItems();
            });
```

You can improve this a little bit by using `ObservableCollection`, and update only the item that was changed. Something like this.

Send the id of the changed element as an argument of a message

```
MessagingCenter.Send(this, "MyItemsChanged", MY_ITEM_ID);
```

Subscribe to that message, find the changed element in your `MyItems` collection, and replace it by refetching that element from your database

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, string>(this, "MyItemsChanged", async (sender, id) => {
                var index = MyItems.IndexOf(MyItems.FirstOrDefault(item => item.id == id));
                MyItems[index] = await GetItemById(id);
            });
```

I assumed that MyItems is defined as `ObservableCollection<MyItem>` and that you have an async method `GetItemByItem(string itemId)` which will fetch your item from your db.

Comment: Hi, For the seccond method, i get this error. " The type arguments for method 'MessagingCenter.Subscribe<TSender, TArgs>(object, string, Action<TSender, TArgs>, TSender)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Replace  MessagingCenter.Subscribe with  MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>

Comment: Hi, Tanks for the reply and sorry for the delay. I have included this into a method. But still, It doesnt trigger when I pass the message from the other content page.

Comment: Replace your Send/Subscription code with this
MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "hi", "1");
 MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, string>(this, "hi", (sender, argument) => {});

Answer (score 0):

I found the clear steps to refresh a page in viewmodel using Messaging center. It will works perfectly to me.

**Step 1:** Add the message when you save a item into your database

```
    MessagingCenter.Send(this, "MyItemsChanged");
```

**Step 2 :** In your View add the following code in OnAppearing method

```
  protected override void OnAppearing()
     {   
    base.OnAppearing();
        _ViewModel.LoadServerRegisteredCitizens();
    //LoadServerRegisteredCitizen is a method which i used to load items inside the listview        
}
```

**Step 3 :** In your view model constructor, subscribe to that message and update reload your items

```
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<CurrentViewModelName>(this, "MyItemsChanged", sender => {
            LoadServerRegisteredCitizens();
            });
```